# Rails PayPal IPN notify_url is not called

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, paypal-ipn

So, I have a router with global IP address (Yeah, I know it will NOT work with the local ones, like 192.168.xx.xx) address and I've triple checked that it IS accessible from the outside.

I'm currently working in the sandbox environment.

I have all my payment options in the hidden :encrypted field (see appropriate railscast) that are being posted to PayPal. On the PayPal side everything is running pretty much smooth - I complete my payment and so on, but IPN is never called. There is simply no log-entry for my action being triggered (no errors/warnings or whatsoever), however there should be at least something.

I've tried to pass the notify_url 2 ways: 1) in the options hash in my purchase model, before being encrypted to :encrypted field; `:notify_url => notify_url` 2) notify_url as a separate hidden field explicitly => `<%= hidden_field_tag :notify_url, notify_url %>` 3) Combination of pts 1 and 2.

But it is hopeless - nothing seems to be working. :(

I have also tried to enabling the IPN in my sandbox business account settings, but that didn't do any help either.

What should I do in this situation ?

P.S I have also tried out the IPN Simulator service, and it seems to be working. What is wrong with it then ?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With trial-n-error, I've finally found a solution!

Never, I repeat, NEVER use "_cart" as a cmd for your payment if you want to use: 1) IPN, 2) PDT validation. Use "_xclick" instead!

That fixed my problem and now both of them working properly!

Hope this will be useful to someone!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had several problems with the rails root_path too, so I had to use:

```
(:notify_url => MyApp::Application.config.domain_url + Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.my_ipn_path) #
```

to ensure the notify_url is well-formed, linking it to the values hash (if you are using something similar to this railcast http://railscasts.com/episodes/141-paypal-basics).

I couldn't make it work at a local enviroment, so I have to test it directly on my staging enviroment, checking the log :)

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've checked the notify_url numberous times. I have even tested the link with the IPN Simulator, and it works like a charm, but with the real payment it doesn't work at all :( I have started to suspect that IPN is disabled in sandbox environment at all. :( 
Don't know if it true, though ... but there is 0 reasons it not to work for my case.

Comment: Damn. It seems, that PDT is not working in sandbox as well (validation part: _notify-synch). It returns 3004 error for correct tx,at combination and FAIL otherwise. Nice support, PayPal. How the hell I'm suppose to develope something, when I'm have no clue if my application is working properly or not. Damn you, PayPal!